# Is it OK that my circuit breaker panel does not latch closed

Tags: electrical, code-compliance, electrical-panel, damage, inspection

I plan on doing some work and having it inspected.
As part of the work I will be switching some normal breakers to AFCI.
Before I get started I notice my panel does not fully latch closed.
The latch appears to be thin sheet metal that has snapped off.

I am wondering if this is a code violation and something I will have to fix.

If so that might really change my plans as I don't see these latches as being sold separately or meant to be replaced.

My town is on the 2011 NEC.
The breaker panel is a 200A GE catalog # TM3020F

[image: closeup of broken panel clip]

Answer (score 2):

### You should be able to replace the latch

Try using a GE TDL106 to replace the broken latch on your panel, although it's not a Code violation, simply annoying to have the door on a NEMA 1 (indoor) panel floating loose like that.  (Some smaller panels lack a door, even.)